# Aero Glass Theme (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, aero, aero-glass

A litle while ago I was on Codeproject and came across a cool little tesxteditor and the whole form was made out of aero-glass, and the whole textbox was too. But I can't find it anymore. Does anybody know where it's gone? Or how I can make my Windows Form completely made out of Aero Glass?

Thank you :)

Comment: What is the question, how to write a cool text editor or how to enable glass?

Comment: sorry nobugz i wasn't clear enough, i edited my question

Comment: It is well described in this blog post: http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2006/06/vista-glass-in-c_17.html

Comment: @nobugz, great link; looks like this should be an answer to me :)

Comment: thank you very much nobugz!!!!!!!!!!! :D you've saved me so much time and trouble, um; why wasn't this an answer? lol +1

Answer (score 2):

This is for windows forms. not for WPF.

[http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2006/04/18/578637.aspx](http://web.archive.org/web/20100501000000*/http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2006/04/18/578637.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you're after...

[Enable Vista glass effect on a borderless WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324398/enable-vista-glass-effect-on-a-borderless-wpf-window)

Comment: thanks Alasdair. I have considered WPF although I don't like the weird effects it has while using it on my computer. I don't know why but all wpf apps seem to run slowly on this computer

Answer (score 0):

So this time with the launch of Windows 7, Microsoft provides the Windows 7 API Code Pack. The Windows 7 API Code Pack not only just allows incorporating the aero glass effect, but many other features which will let you to work more conveniently with Windows 7.

The Windows API code pack allows developers to develop those features which are not available with .NET Framework. So to get started visit:

```
Windows® Code Pack API for Windows 7 & Windows Vista
```

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

```
Windows Training Kit
```

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1C333F06-FADB-4D93-9C80-402621C600E7&displaylang=en

The training kit includes the demos and presentations, hand-on labs for developers. I haven't yet started with Windows 7 development. But as soon as I get started I will blog some demo for Windows 7.

Comment: You'd better document what specific class in the code pack helps implement glass.  Pretty sure there isn't one, other than in the sample code (searchapp).

Comment: GlassForm and GlassWindow implement glass.  As for controls on the form, good luck.