# Show WPF window with WindowStyle=None and no resize

Tags: wpf, resize, styles, window, border

I'm trying to display a window with a border like with `WindowStyle="None"` (picture 2), but without the option to resize it!

When I set the `ResizeMode="NoResize"` the border disappears (picture 1)

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386486/wpf-make-window-unresizeable-but-keep-the-frame

Comment: Your assumptions are completly wrong. WindowStyle="None"  makes your border disappear, like in picture 1. ResizeMode="NoResize" disables all options to resize the window, IF a border is present.

Comment: @rwank Mmmh, nope, `WindowStyle="None"` doesn't make your border disappear UNLESS you set `ResizeMode="NoResize"`. @Xenogenesis is right. But it is indeed a duplicate, though.

Comment: @rwank Thanks, I wasn't able to find a related question, maybe I was to fixed upon the 'Window' wording except using 'Frame'
@almulo Hello again, you're right, with no ResizeMode specified and `None` as WindowStyle there is a border

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by setting the Max and Min size properties to the same values, thus forcing the Window to have a fixed size. Something like this should work:

```
Window w = new Window();
w.MaxHeight = w.MinHeight = 300;
w.MinWidth = w.MaxWidth = 400;
w.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
w.Show();
```

Comment: I agree on the fixed size and the border, but the resize cursor is still showing => Some users would be annoyed by that

Comment: The window's border (the so called "chrome") is part of Win32 rather than WPF, so I don't think you can change it directly in pure WPF. 
A solution, at this point, would be to use NoResize and then draw your own border around the window.